# Zend Framework 1 Routing issue exception

Tags: php, zend-framework

Hi all I'm having an issue with my routing in `Zend Framework 1`. I keep getting this error:

```
Exception information:

Message: Action "testfree" does not exist and was not trapped in __call()
Stack trace:

#0 Zend/Controller/Action.php(518): Zend_Controller_Action->__call('testfreeAction', Array)
#1 Zend/Controller/Dispatcher/Standard.php(295): Zend_Controller_Action->dispatch('testfreeAction')
#2 Zend/Controller/Front.php(954): Zend_Controller_Dispatcher_Standard->dispatch(Object(Zend_Controller_Request_Http), Object(Zend_Controller_Response_Http))
#3 Zend/Application/Bootstrap/Bootstrap.php(97): Zend_Controller_Front->dispatch()
#4 Zend/Application.php(366): Zend_Application_Bootstrap_Bootstrap->run()
#5 public/index.php(46): Zend_Application->run()
#6 {main}  

Request Parameters:

array (
  'controller' => 'journal',
  'action' => 'testfree',
  'journal_id' => '23',
  'module' => 'default',
)
```

This is my link in the `html`

```
<a class="button" 
   href="<?php echo $this->url(
       array(
           'module'     => 'default', 
           'controller' => 'journal', 
           'action'     => 'testfree', 
           'journal_id' => $this->journal->id
       ), 
       null, 
       false) 
?>">Test Free</a>
```

I have a `Controller` called JournalController in the default subdirectory of modules. It has a method called testfree( ). I would like to call this method.

This is the code for the `Controller`

```
public function testfree(){
        echo "test free";
        die();
    }
```

I have no experience working with `Zend`. I am trying to make a change to a piece of work a colleague of mine did. Can anyone advise me on where I am going wrong? Do I need to update something in the `Bootstrap.php` file?

Any help is much appreciated

Comment: Hey! Please consider turning `error display` `off` on production environment!!
[http://isel.lightboxdigital.ie/journal/testfree](http://isel.lightboxdigital.ie/journal/testfree)

Comment: Simplest way is to use zftool to avoid this type of problems.

Answer (score 3):

`testfree` is an action so try to add **'Action'** to the name:

```
public function testfreeAction(){
  ...
}
```